# How to update each row in a table Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, procedure

How can I create a procedure to verify each row of a table and update a field according to the established statement?
I have 4 fields that I work with

1. `SYS_UPDATE_PING`
2. `UPDATE_PING`
3. `PING_STATUS`
4. `TIME_OUT_PING`

Here is my code:

```
create or replace procedure SP_DASHBOARD_PINGSTATUS is
begin
  declare
  sp_ping_final number;
  BEGIN
        Update rsmes.tb_op_pc_monitoring_v4 t
         set t.sys_update_ping = sysdate;
   for c in (select ((SYS_UPDATE_PING - UPDATE_PING)*60*60*24) as PING_RESULT into sp_ping_final from TB_OP_PC_MONITORING_V4)
     loop
       sp_ping_final := c.ping_result;
       if c.ping_result <= 5 then
        Update rsmes.tb_op_pc_monitoring_v4 tg
        set tg.ping_status = 'OK',
            tg.time_out_ping = sp_ping_final;
       else
        Update rsmes.tb_op_pc_monitoring_v4 tn
        set tn.ping_status = 'NG',
            tn.time_out_ping = sp_ping_final;
        end if;
       end loop;
        commit;
  END;
end SP_DASHBOARD_PINGSTATUS;
```

I make a time difference between SYS_UPDATE_PING and UPDATE_PING, if the result in seconds is less than 5 it must update the PING_STATUS field to OK and put the seconds difference in TIME_OUT_PING, otherwise it will update NG and put the seconds difference in TIME_OUT_PING,
I want it to compare on each row but it updates me on all fields instead of one by one.

I know I'm forgetting something but could you help me find my fault and know the solution?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `UPDATE` statements miss the `WHERE` clause. Without it, you're always updating all rows in the table.

It means that cursor should contain some kind of an `ID`, which you'll the reuse in `UPDATE`. For example:

```
for c in (select id,                            --> this
                ((sys_update_ping - ...)
         ) loop
  ...
  update tb_op_pc_monitoring_v4 tg set
    tg.ping_status = 'OK'
    where tg.id = c.id;                         --> this
  ...
end loop;
```

Also, you don't `SELECT INTO` in cursor. Remove the `sp_ping_final` entirely.

---

Finally, I'd say that you don't need PL/SQL (loop especially) at all. The whole code you wrote can be rewritten into a single

```
UPDATE tb_op_pc_monitoring_v4 tg
   SET tg.ping_status =
          CASE
             WHEN (SYSDATE - tg.update_ping) * 60 * 60 * 24 <= 5 THEN 'OK'
             ELSE 'NG'
          END,
       tg.time_out_ping = (SYSDATE - tg.update_ping) * 60 * 60 * 24;
```

which should work way faster than your row-by-row processing.

Comment: It works great, thank you very much without your help I would not have been able to forward my project.